# Best way to take complete content image of HTML

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I want to take an image of the complete Html page and attach it to an email.
I have tried using Protractor with chrome drivers. It works well on OS with GUI like MAC, Windows but when it went to Cloud server like AMAZON AWS chrome starts crashing with an error

Protractor Version: 
Version 5.4.2

Chrome Version: 
Google Chrome 77.0.3865.120

Please let me know if there is any other way using which I can achieve this functionality better

[image]

Protractor Config File:

```
     exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['sg-image.js'],
framework: 'jasmine2',
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'useAutomationExtension': false,
    'args': ['--disable-gpu','-disable-dev-shm-usage','--no-sandbox','- 
            disable-popup-blocking','--start-maximized','--disable-web- 
           security','--allow-running-insecure-content','--disable-infobars']
}
        // onPrepare: function() {
//     global.screenShotUtils = new screenShotUtils({
//         browserInstance : browser
//     });
// }
```

};

Comment: It works locally but throws an error on a remote, cloud-based instance?  What's the error?

Comment: @orde i have attached screenshot

Comment: Adding a Protractor config file might be useful as well

Comment: @YuriyGerasimovich already added that. check the edited post this is how config looks like

Comment: use : https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image ... First getPageSource of required page and then use the library to convert to image

Answer (score 0):

I don't see headless chrome being used to run this. May be that is the issue

Try changing this

```
'args': ['--disable-gpu','-disable-dev-shm-usage','--no-sandbox','- 
            disable-popup-blocking','--start-maximized','--disable-web- 
           security','--allow-running-insecure-content','--disable-infobars']
```

to

```
'args': ['--headless','--disable-gpu','-disable-dev-shm-usage','--no-sandbox','- 
            disable-popup-blocking','--start-maximized','--disable-web- 
           security','--allow-running-insecure-content','--disable-infobars']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `xvfb-run` on your system where you run your tests and start the process like this:

`xvfb-run -a --server-args="-screen 0 1920x1080x24" protractor protractor.conf.js`

what it does, per my understanding, is it buffers visual representation of the process in non-GUI systems, which allows you to capture screenshots as well as video recording

That's what working for me